# How can I get both GameObjects children in one loop?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
for (int i = 0; i < doors.Count; i++)
        {
            if (doorLockState == true)
            {
             var t =    doors[i].GetComponentInChildren<Transform>();
                // Color in red
            }
            else
            {
                var t = doors[i].GetComponentInChildren<Transform>();
                // Color in green
            }
        }
```

I'm using the variable t in both cases just for testing for debug.

doors[i] have two doors each loop.
doors[0] contains two items and each item have one children.
I want to get the children of each of them. Now the way it is I'm getting just the items in doors but not the child of each of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since each item contains only 1 child, you can use `Transform.GetChild(0)` to get the first and only child. The rest is simple, loop through every item in doors[i] and get their child.

```
foreach(Transform child in dooors[i].GetComponentsInChildren<Transform>())
{
    Transform childOfChild = child.GetChild(0);
}
```

Comment: Working and if there are more then one childs ? I did a mistake there are two childs each item not one. At index 0 and index 1. I could add another line Transform childOfChild1 = child.GetChild(1); but maybe there is a better way ?

Comment: @DubiDuboni The foreach loop will work for any number of child. If there are more than 1 childOfChild, you could make a for loop using childCount(). Ex: `for(int i = 0; i < child.childCount(); i++)`